S3 HTML object is downloaded by the browser rather than rendered
I have provisioned an AWS bucket in AWS S3:
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucketA" {
  provider = aws.route53_role
  bucket = "helloworld.com"

  tags = {
    Name        = "domain-bucket00"
    Environment = "test"
  }

}

I have furthermore uploaded HTML index object to the bucket:
resource "aws_s3_object" "bucketA-index" {
  provider = aws.route53_role
  key        = "index.html"
  bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.bucketA.id
  source     = "index.html"
  content_type = "text/html"
}

But when I browse the bucket and the object, the browser downloads the page rather than display it.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
P.S. I open the S3 object (index.html) in the browser by using the object URL: http://...s3.ca-central....index.html
This answer is not an answer to this question as that question is talking about local links - I am asking about links to objects stored on S3.

See here

This most often happens when the file the browser is opened has a content type that it cannot display so confirm what content type is being returned when the browser access the object. Looks like it is being set to text/html but just double check what the browser is seeing when you open it. Perhaps try a different browser as well.

Yup. It's working in Firefox but not in Chrome (shrug)
